# Two Klein Bottles Sewn Together?

Tags: general-topology

So, I'm pretty sure at least some of you know what a Klein Bottle is. If not, a Klein Bottle, named after German mathematician Felix Klein, is basically a shape that has one side and no edge. You basically would get this if you took 2 Mobius Loops and sew them together, which creates a shape(The Klein Bottle)that requires a 4-dimensional space to exist. Here's what I wonder though.

What would happen if you kept this going. What would 2 Klein Bottles create if you tried sewing them together? Is that even possible?

Comment: A Mobius strip has a single edge, so it's pretty clear what it means to sew two of them together.  A Klein bottle, as you point out, has no edge, so it's not all all clear what sewing two of them together means.  Similarly, if you ask, "What do you get if you sew two spheres together," I answer, "Sew then together how?"

Comment: By the way, the Klein bottle does not require a 4-dimensional space to exist. It exists all on its own, using the quotient topology induced by gluing the two Möbius strips together

Comment: Klein bottles don't need 4D space to exist, they just need 4D space to not self-intersect.

Comment: Well, that's how you can model them in 3D space. But to see them in their true form, with no intersection, you need 4D space.

Comment: I am very curious about the same fact that what happened if you glue the surface of a Klein bottle onto/into another? can someone provide an animation or video or research paper on that?

Comment: Perhaps OP means a *solid* Klein bottle?

Answer (score 2):

For each $n$, define the *twisted $n$-sphere bundle* to be the space

$$
S^n \times I / (x,0)\sim(\alpha_0^{(n+1)}(x),1)\,,
$$
where $I$ is the standard interval and $\alpha_0^{(n+1)}(x)$ flips the first coordinate of $x$ (considered as a point in $n+1$-dimensional space), leaving the others alone. In other words, we take a hollow $n$-cylinder and glue the ends together via $\alpha_0^{(n+1)}$. As examples:

- The twisted $0$-sphere bundle is the boundary of the Möbius strip (a $0$-sphere is a pair of points, which are interchanged by the antipodal map).
- The twisted $1$-sphere is the Klein bottle.

Define the *twisted $n$-disk bundle* to be the space
$$
D^n \times I/(x,0)\sim (\alpha_0^{(n)}(x),1)\,,
$$
where $D^n$ is the closed $n$-disk. As examples:

- The twisted $1$-disk bundle is the Möbius strip (a $1$-disk is the same as the interval $I$).
- The twisted $2$-disk bundle is called the *solid Klein bottle*. It is a three dimensional manifold whose boundary is the Klein bottle.

More generally, it is fairly intuitive to see that the boundary of the twisted $n+1$-disk bundle is the twisted $n$-sphere bundle.

Now what happens when we glue together two twisted $n$-disk bundles along their boundaries? Since the result of gluing together two $n$-disks along their boundaries is the $n$-sphere, we know that we have an $S^n$-bundle of some sort. Moreover, the gluing map at the boundary is given by $\alpha_0^{(n)}$ on each disk, so after gluing the two disks together (taking the gluing to take place in the $n+1$-th dimension), we see that the gluing on the boundary is precisely $\alpha_0^{(n+1)}$. In other words, when we glue together two twisted $n$-disk bundles along their boundaries, we get the twisted $n$-sphere bundle.

Putting all this together:

- The twisted $0$-sphere bundle is the boundary of the Möbius strip (the twisted $1$-disk bundle).
- Gluing two Möbius strips along their boundaries yields a twisted $1$-sphere bundle (a Klein bottle).
- The Klein bottle is the boundary of the twisted $2$-disk bundle (the solid Klein bottle).
- Gluing two solid Klein bottles along their boundaries yields a twisted $2$-sphere bundle.
- The twisted $2$-sphere bundle is the boundary of the twisted $3$-disk bundle.
- Gluing two twisted $3$-disk bundles along their boundaries yields a twisted $3$-sphere bundle...

... and so on.

Answer (score -1):

all I can assume is that if this shape follows the same rules as other shapes and when you glue one side of a shape to an other identical shape both shapes loos one side and as a Klein bottle has only one side you would end up with a shape with no sides.

In short gluing the surfaces of two Klein bottles together would create a shape with no edges, no sides, no corners and no volume. It`s only characteristics are that it is curved and looped.

I know I did not use any math to come up with my answer but I like it so pleas don`t delete it.